# How to get data of dynamically nested Select using foreach values in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am dynamically populating the data and trying to display it.

I am getting the option id's of the Select elements, but I am not sure how do I get the parent element.

I tried to add `hidden` input but I cannot get value but I was not able to get the value(known issue)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
 data() {
    return {
    variations : [
   {
      "id":1,
      "variationName":"Material",
      "created_at":"2020-08-20T16:23:18.000000Z",
      "updated_at":"2020-08-20T16:23:18.000000Z",
      "variant_options":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "variants_id":1,
            "variationOptionName":"Plastic",
            "created_at":"2020-08-20T16:45:15.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2020-08-20T16:45:15.000000Z"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "variants_id":1,
            "variationOptionName":"Wood",
            "created_at":"2020-08-20T16:45:45.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2020-08-20T16:45:45.000000Z"
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "variants_id":1,
            "variationOptionName":"glass",
            "created_at":"2020-08-20T16:46:23.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2020-08-20T16:46:23.000000Z"
         },
         {
            "id":4,
            "variants_id":1,
            "variationOptionName":"pvc",
            "created_at":"2020-08-20T16:47:15.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2020-08-20T16:47:15.000000Z"
         },
         {
            "id":5,
            "variants_id":1,
            "variationOptionName":"unknown",
            "created_at":"2020-08-20T16:47:58.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2020-08-20T16:47:58.000000Z"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "variationName":"color",
      "created_at":"2020-08-20T16:25:14.000000Z",
      "updated_at":"2020-08-20T16:25:14.000000Z",
      "variant_options":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "variationName":"type",
      "created_at":"2020-08-20T16:25:45.000000Z",
      "updated_at":"2020-08-20T16:25:45.000000Z",
      "variant_options":[
         {
            "id":6,
            "variants_id":3,
            "variationOptionName":"working",
            "created_at":"2020-08-20T16:48:44.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2020-08-20T16:48:44.000000Z"
         }
      ]
   }
],
      variationOptions: [],
    };
  },
  mounted: function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.variations.length; i++) {
      this.variationOptions.push({
        values: [],
      });
    }
  },
  methods: {},
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Variation Name</td>
          <td>Variation Values</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(items,index) in variations">
          <td>{{items.variationName}}</td>
          <td>
            <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2" v-model="variationOptions[index]['values']">
              <option v-for="(variationOptions,index) in  items.variant_options" :key="variationOptions.id" :value="variationOptions.id">{{variationOptions.variationOptionName}}</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          {{variationOptions}}
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also I am getting the following error.

```
 *Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined"*
```

Where am I wrong. I would appreciate if you could take a moment to explain

**Update:**

I have updated the `values` with `item.id` and getting the data as I expect.

But the format is

```
 [ { "items": { "id": [] } }, { "items": { "id": [] } }, { "items": { "id": [] } } ]
```

How do I remove the items and id from the result.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue)

Comment: It seems you should use `variationOptions` instead of `variations` in the template `<tr v-for="(items,index) in variations">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a snippet that is a bit more logical to me:

- it structures selected values dynamically by the `variationName` (so works for any number of variations)
- gives the ability to pass the whole selected `variant_options` object to the select:

```
<option
  v-for="(option, idxj) in item.variant_options"
  :key="`options-${ idxi }-${ idxj }`"
  :value="option.variationOptionName"
  <!-- if you set it to :value="option",
  then the whole object is passed -->
>
  {{ option.variationOptionName }}
</option>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    variationOptionsArray() {
      return Object.values(this.variationOptions)
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      variations: [{
          "id": 1,
          "variationName": "Material",
          "created_at": "2020-08-20T16:23:18.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2020-08-20T16:23:18.000000Z",
          "variant_options": [{
              "id": 1,
              "variants_id": 1,
              "variationOptionName": "Plastic",
              "created_at": "2020-08-20T16:45:15.000000Z",
              "updated_at": "2020-08-20T16:45:15.000000Z"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "variants_id": 1,
              "variationOptionName": "Wood",
              "created_at": "2020-08-20T16:45:45.000000Z",
              "updated_at": "2020-08-20T16:45:45.000000Z"
            },
            {
              "id": 3,
              "variants_id": 1,
              "variationOptionName": "glass",
              "created_at": "2020-08-20T16:46:23.000000Z",
              "updated_at": "2020-08-20T16:46:23.000000Z"
            },
            {
              "id": 4,
              "variants_id": 1,
              "variationOptionName": "pvc",
              "created_at": "2020-08-20T16:47:15.000000Z",
              "updated_at": "2020-08-20T16:47:15.000000Z"
            },
            {
              "id": 5,
              "variants_id": 1,
              "variationOptionName": "unknown",
              "created_at": "2020-08-20T16:47:58.000000Z",
              "updated_at": "2020-08-20T16:47:58.000000Z"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "variationName": "color",
          "created_at": "2020-08-20T16:25:14.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2020-08-20T16:25:14.000000Z",
          "variant_options": [{
              "id": 1,
              "variants_id": 1,
              "variationOptionName": "Orange",
              "created_at": "2020-08-20T16:45:45.000000Z",
              "updated_at": "2020-08-20T16:45:45.000000Z"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "variants_id": 2,
              "variationOptionName": "Red",
              "created_at": "2020-08-20T16:45:45.000000Z",
              "updated_at": "2020-08-20T16:45:45.000000Z"
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "variationName": "type",
          "created_at": "2020-08-20T16:25:45.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2020-08-20T16:25:45.000000Z",
          "variant_options": [{
            "id": 6,
            "variants_id": 3,
            "variationOptionName": "working",
            "created_at": "2020-08-20T16:48:44.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-08-20T16:48:44.000000Z"
          }]
        }
      ],
      variationOptions: {},
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.variations.length; i++) {
      Vue.set(this.variationOptions, this.variations[i].variationName, [])
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    As Object: {{ variationOptions }}<br />
    As Array: {{ variationOptionsArray }}
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Variation Name</th>
          <th>Variation Values</th>
          <th>Selected</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(item, idxi) in variations" :key="`item-${ idxi }`">
          <td>
            {{ item.variationName }}
          </td>
          <td>
            <select multiple v-model="variationOptions[item.variationName]">
              <option v-for="(option, idxj) in item.variant_options" :key="`options-${ idxi }-${ idxj }`" :value="option.variationOptionName">
                {{ option.variationOptionName }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            {{ variationOptions[item.variationName] }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

The biggest difference is that I didn't store the selected values in an **Array** but in an **Object** - but I provided the values also in an **computed Array** format for more convenience.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please brief me on idxi in the v-for.. It's new to me

Comment: idxi is just an abbreviation for index or i. Usually I use idx (from the word index), but in this case there is another v-for inside that (and that is conventionally j - so idxj). It’s just a shorter word than index, but more expressive (to me) than a simple i.

Comment: Thanks for the explaining.. I have updated the values to put out id instead of name.. I am getting this error - select multiple v-model="variationOptions[item.id]"> expects an Array value for its binding, but got Undefined.. I am getting results as expected..

Comment: Did you change the loop in the **mounted()** hook? The error says it’s missing the inital select array.

Comment: yes, I updated that too..  for (let i = 0; i < this.variations.length; i++) {
      Vue.set(this.variationOptions, this.variations[i].id, []);
    }

Comment: No error in the fiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/eurodgj7/

Comment: I would appreciate if you could please take a look in this question.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646606/saving-dynamic-select-values-in-database-laravel .. Suggestions would be much appreciated..

Comment: @mightyteja for avoiding the warning: change the `mounted` to `created` - that is an earlier lifecycle hook, before rendering the template. The warning comes from the fact that the `validationOptions` object is set up AFTER the template has been mounted (so the values & variables in it are initiated). If you change to `created`, then you set up the function BEFORE the template is mounted, so the `validationOptions` object is ready to accept the **multiple** `select`s

Comment: @mightyteja I looked at your other question - I think the problem is that you're not parsing the data from string to array.