# Saving Dynamic Select Values in database - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent, vuejs2

I am working an multiple select Boxes in a form which are rendered dynamically.

Here in the below scenario I am mapping the selecttion to the parent title.

The example result is  `{ "1": [ 2 ], "2": [ 1, 3 ] }`

```html
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Variation Name</td>
              <td>Variation Values</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Size</td>
              <td>
                <select multiple="multiple">
                  <option value="2">Medium</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Color</td>
              <td>
                <select multiple="multiple">
                  <option value="1">White</option>
                  <option value="3">Blue</option>
                  <option value="4">Black</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

I am passing the result to the Laravel Controller so that I could save the response..

I am not sure how do I save the data to the database..

```
public function itemsStore(Request $request)
    {
        $items_arrays = array($request['itemsArray'], true);
        dd(items_arrays);
    }
```

The `dd` result is

```
array:2 [
  0 => "{"1":[2],"2":[1,3]}"
  1 => true
]
```

How do I save the values to database in the respective format

```
item_id | item_value_id
   1             2
   2             1
   2             3
```

I am populating the above object using Vue. Sending the data to controller through axios library.
[Fiddle](http://%20jsfiddle.net/eurodgj7)

Comment: How are you submitting the form i.e. are you using ajax or just the standard form submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **PHP** you have different ways to define an `array`.

One way is to define it by setting its values explicitly, like:

```
<?php
  $my_array_1 = array("first" => 0, "second" => 1) // or;
  $my_array_2 = array(0, 1, 2);
?>
```

The arrays can store mixed values, so this is valid:

```
<?php
  $my_array_3 = array(0, "one", 2)
?>
```

Your array is like the one before:

```
<?php
  $items_arrays = array($request['itemsArray'], true);
?>
```

The **PHP** `array()` doesn't have a parameter only the items added, so the `true` you put at the end is just the second element of your array.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Based on that your `dd` outputs exactly what you added when you defined the array:

```
array:2 [
  0 => "{"1":[2],"2":[1,3]}" // this is the string from $request['itemsArray']
  1 => true // this is the second element you added
]
```

I think your problem is that you need to parse the `string` that you receive in your `$request['itemsArray']`.

1. So, first:

```
public function itemsStore(Request $request)
  {
    $json = json_decode($request['itemsArray']);
    // $json is now an associative array in PHP
    // something like: array(1 => array(2), 2 => array(1, 3))
    
    // $items_arrays = array($request['itemsArray'], true);
    // dd(items_arrays);
  }
```

2. Then you need to flatten this associative array:

```
public function itemsStore(Request $request)
  {
    $json = json_decode($request['itemsArray']);
    // $json is now an associative array in PHP
    // something like: array(1 => array(2), 2 => array(1, 3))
    $items_arrays = [];
    foreach(json as $key1 => $val1) {
      foreach($val1 as $key2 => $val2) {
        $items_array[] = array($key1 => $val2);
      }
    }
    // $items_arrays = array($request['itemsArray'], true);
    dd(items_arrays);
  }
```

(`json_decode` has optional parameters: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Of course, you should check the `$request` before working with it - authentication & validation are important!

---

Sorry, if the syntax is not correct - I haven't worked with PHP for over a year and wrote the samples by heart (no checking). But the idea is surely correct:

1. Get the data from the request (Validate the data! This is not required for the process, but required for a production environment!)
2. Transform it from the string format to PHP array
3. Read it in a final array (as you need it in the end)
4. Put the final format in the database

Answer (score 0):

you need to give some name to dynamic select.
Fore example if you have a list [size, color] of attributes you could do

- ...
- ...

In the server side you will receive a array param attr[]

$attr = request()->attr;

it should looks like
$attr['size'] => [ your size selected]
$attr['color'] => your color selected.

You could make a dump to watch the form.

I hope it helps, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for response. Here is the fiddle on how I a getting the data.  jsfiddle.net/eurodgj7. Any Enhancement would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this alternate

Make sure in your html you set the name attribute to an array like below

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="sizes[]" id="sizes">
```

Then to store it you can get it in the controller like

```
$sizes = $request->input('sizes');//it will give you string separated by commas
$sizes = explode(',', $sizes);// to separate it explode the string

// save it to database
```

Similarly for other inputs like multi select colors input you can use the above steps

Comment: Thank youy for quick reponse. I am using Vue to populate the objects.  I am storing the above object to itemsArray while passing to laravel controller. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eurodgj7/