# explode Array results and apply foreach

Tags: php, arrays, regex, laravel

Here is my Array,

```
array:2 [
  0 => "{"1":[2],"2":[1,3]}"
  1 => true
]
```

How do I display the above array in the respective format

```
item_id | item_value_id
   1             2
   2             1
   2             3
```

I have tried using explode but unfortunately I am unable to parse b/w the brackets.

Here is what I have tried

```
        // dd(explode("[]", $value));
        // dd(preg_split('/"/', $value));
        // dd(preg_split('/(?![^][]*\])/', $value));
```

I am not getting the result as  expected.

Update:

I wrapped the array around json_decode and I got

```
        foreach ($arrays as $key => $value) {
                    # code... 
                    $json = json_decode($value);
   
//Another foreach 
                    foreach ($json as $key => $value1) {
                        # code...
                        dd($value1);
    
                    }
                }
```

**Results**

```
**dd($json)**
 /**
            {#1386
              +"1": array:1 [
                0 => 2
              ]
              +"2": array:2 [
                0 => 1
                1 => 3
              ]
            }
        */

**dd($value)**

   /**
    array:1 [
      0 => 2
    ]
    **/
```

Comment: That's looks like json. So json_decode()?

Comment: How did you get this data?

Comment: This is a follow up of the the question.. I trying to save the result in database https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63638457/how-to-get-data-of-dynamically-nested-select-using-foreach-values-in-vue @nice_dev

Comment: Nice. You are close now. Just use 2 nested loops.

Comment: when I try to loop again it's throwing me error --- "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: Question updated. Was some caching error.. No error. But still I am not sure to split the values

Comment: Is that display you want to do in an HTML format?

Comment: No, I am trying to save it to database..

Comment: well you're trying to loop an object, so set true to json_decode as second param which will turn it into an array

Comment: yes, I was able to save the data with the answer provided.. I just modified the answer since the logic is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't loop an object unless it implements Countable or ArrayAccess interface.
Assuming your model name is `Model`, you can do a bulk insert like below:

```
<?php

$rows = [];

$arrays = json_decode($data[0],true);

foreach ($arrays as $key1 => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        $rows[] = [
            'item_id' => $key1,
            'item_value_id' => $value2
        ];
    }
}

if(count($rows) > 0){
    Model::insert($rows); // bulk insert
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if i'm entirely correct here, but I believe this is what you're asking for:

```
<?php

$data = [
    0 => '{"1":[2],"2":[1,3]}',
    1 => true
];


$decoded_json = json_decode($data[0], true);


?>

<table>
    <thead>
        <th>item_id</th>
        <th>item_value_id</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

   <?php foreach ($decoded_json as $item_key => $item){?>
        <?php foreach ($item as $item_data){ ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $item_key?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item_data?></td>
            </tr>


        <?php }?>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```